# Improving nested objects filtering speed

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, c#-4.0, webforms

Here's a problem I experience (simplified example):
Let's say I have several tables:
[image]

One customer can have mamy products and a product can have multiple features.

On my asp.net front-end I have a grid with customer info:

something like this:

```
Name   Address   
John   222 1st st     
Mark   111 2nd st
```

What I need is an ability to filter customers by feature. So, I have a dropdown list of available features that are connected to a customer.

What I currently do:
1. I return `DataTable` of Customers from stored procedure. I store it in viewstate
2. I return `DataTable` of features connected to customers from stored procedure. I store it in viewstate
3. On filter selected, I run stored procedure again with new feature_id filter where I do joins again to only show customers that have selected feature.

**My problem: It is very slow.**

I think that possible solutions would be:
1. On page load return ALL data in one viewstate variable. So basically three lists of nested objects. This will make my page load slow.
2. Perform async loazing in some smart way. How?

Any better solutions?

**Edit:**
this is a simplified example, so I also need to filter customer by property that is connected through 6 tables to table Customer.

Comment: Your storing an entire list of customers in ViewState? Yeah...probably not the best idea. Also, you say, "My problem: It is very slow." Which part? You listed 3 steps, which part is slow?

Comment: @aquinas, Storing whole thing in viewstate is slow, also each filtering action is slow since it goes back to db.

Comment: Why can't you just wait for the user to select the feature and THEN select customers who have that feature from the database. I.e., make ONE db trip? E.g., `select * from cutomers where customerid in (select customerid from customerproduct natural join product natural join feature where featureid='whateverTheUserSelected')`

Comment: @keyboardP, yes it has all the proper indexes.

Comment: @aquinas, it is still more trips since I need to load all the features that are connected to customers. Also, I want to show all customer info by default.  Also, there's no table customerfeature.

Comment: I know, I updated my SQL :). Why do you need to load all features connected to customers? Your question just said you need to show the customers who have a selected feature. Is your customer grid showing customers *and* all their features?

Comment: @aquinas, no, let's say I have 10000 features, but only 100 features are connected to customers through table Product. I need to load dropdown list with those 100 features on page load anyway. when they select a feature I filter customers. No I don't show all of their features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I deal with these scenarios is by passing in Xml to SQL and then running a join against that. So Xml would look something like:

```
<Features><Feat Id="2" /><Feat Id="5" /><feat Id="8" /></Features>
```

Then you can pass that Xml into SQL (depending on what version of SQL there are different ways), but in the newer version's its a lot easier than it used to be:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20847/Passing-Arrays-in-SQL-Parameters-using-XML-Data-Ty

Also, don't put any of that in ViewState; there's really no reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

Storing an entire list of customers in ViewState is going to be hideously slow; storing all information for all customers in ViewState is going to be worse, unless your entire customer base is very very small, like about 30 records.

For a start, why are you loading all the customers into ViewState?  If you have any significant number of customers, load the data a page at a time.  That will at least reduce the amount of data flowing over the wire and might speed up your stored procedure as well.

In your position, I would focus on optimizing the data retrieval first (including minimizing the amount you return), and then worry about faster ways to store and display it.  If you're up against unusual constraints that prevent this (very slow database; no profiling tools; not allowed to change stored procedures) than please let us know.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Basically mi idea to store all items in viewstate, was due to the fact that I can filter on the customers without going back to the database. and just fitlering my datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: Include whatever criteria you need to filter on in your query, only return and render the requested records. No need to use viewstate.

Solution 2: Retrieve some reasonable page limit of customers, filter on the browser with javascript. Allow easy navigation to the next page.